# Tweepy y Python, ¿Por qué me falla ahora?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

Antes de que Elon comprará Twitter, tenía acceso a la API de Twitter y tenía configurados varios tweets para que, con un crontab, se ejecutaran automáticamente los días y las horas que yo quería. Los scripts tenían este esquema:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tweepy

#Coloca dentro de las comillas tus claves...
CONSUMER_KEY = '(key)'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '(key)'

ACCESS_KEY = '(key)'
ACCESS_SECRET = '(key)'

#En esta parte nos identifica para poder realizar operaciones
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

x = tweepy.API(auth)

x.update_status('Test')
```

En la última línea definía el texto que quería que se publicase en los tweets. Esto me iba perfecto y con el crontab se publicaban a la hora que yo quería.

Llegó Musk y la cosa dejó de funcionar y si intento ejecutarlo manualmente, me aparece este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    x.update_status('Test')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 1128, in update_status
    ), status=status, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 257, in request
    raise Unauthorized(resp)
tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
32 - Could not authenticate you.
```

Me indica que no estoy autorizado, pero en la web de https://developer.twitter.com/ ya me autorizé y he comprobado hoy mismo que tengo los permisos para publicar tweets.

¿Alguien sabe que puedo hacer para volver a publicar tweets?

Comment: Comprobaste que el token no se haya regenerado?

Comment: Lo regeneré, y le puse los permisos para publicar tweets